# How to store UITableView content for next launches?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

In my app, user adding some values to each line of the `UITableView`. But when I exit and launch the app for second time, the list become empty as normally. How can I store the values of the `UITableView` when an data entered or deleted?

Comment: You can store user input into memory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because you are not saving the values permanenlty .There are different options available to you for storing small data in app . Most common are

1 : NSUserDefaults

2 : Plist

Answer (score 1):

You can used any following thing for store data withing the application

[CoreData (Introduction to Core Data Programming Guide)](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/cdProgrammingGuide.html)

[PList (About Information Property List Files - Apple Developer)](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/AboutInformationPropertyListFiles.html)

[SQLite](http://www.appcoda.com/sqlite-database-ios-app-tutorial/)

[NSUserDefault](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSUserDefaults_Class/)